# Exterior grading where brick meets stone foundation

Tags: waterproofing, exterior, grading

I'm wondering how my soil should be graded where my exterior brick meets my stone foundation.

The first photo below shows my soil coming up above my brick line, while the left photo shows the soil below the brick line.

Should I clear out all this soil so it doesn't reach the brick line?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Houses that I am familiar with have vents ( no mortar) in the bottom course of brick , so the soil must be below the brick . I like to keep the soil more than 2 inches below the brick to look for termite or ant tunnels up to the vents. Even if you don't have vents I would not want the soil over the brick keeping the mortar damp.